# Tomcat7 does not respond

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp, tomcat7

I am writing my very first application using Spring framework.
I stuck on first step. After I start the tomcat server, I only see an HTTP Status 404.[What I see...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFBDd.png)

Here is my project view.[Project View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HujJJ.png)

Could it be tomcat7 configuration? Or maven configuration.

I would be grateful for any help.

My code is below.

```
May 19, 2016 3:00:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production
environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
May 19, 2016 3:00:07 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 19, 2016 3:00:07 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 19, 2016 3:00:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 973 ms
May 19, 2016 3:00:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 19, 2016 3:00:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
May 19, 2016 3:00:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 19, 2016 3:00:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 19, 2016 3:00:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 629 ms
```

HomeController.java

```
@Controller 
public class HomeController {
@RequestMapping("/")
public static String welcome(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("greeting", "Witaj w sklepie Internetowym!");
    model.addAttribute("tagline", "UDAŁO SIĘ");
    return "welcome";
}
```

}

welcome.jsp

```html
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome our SHOP!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.6/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <section>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
          <h1> ${greeting} </h1>
          <p>${tagline}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>

  </html>
```

web.xml

```html
<web-app  version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" >
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DefaultServelet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DefaultServelet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

DefaultServelet-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:compose-scan base-package="com.tom.webstore"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.serwelet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

`

Comment: Check your tomact logs and post the same.

Comment: de you use eclipse to start your tomcat ? if so, open tomcat server, and verify that in server locations you use Tomcat installation and not workspace metadata.

Comment: Why is your project using Java 5 and Tomcat 7? I wouldn't start projects based on that anymore.

Comment: i think you are missing the project name in the URL, mostly you have to add it to the url http://localhost:8080/myappName/

Comment: 1) Could you post the log trace of tomcat?

Comment: And also upgrade your version of 1.5 JDK to the version 1.7 .